# After I add the time and date to the original post view, it cannot be displayed (the simulator is blank), I am sure there is no error

Tags: ios

I would like to include time for publishing articles

When these date functions are not added, it runs normally

I have tried many ways but it is not feasible, I hope you can give me a little help, any reply is the greatest encouragement to my study, thank you

```
if let date = document.get("date") as? String{

cell.CurrentTime.text = postArray[indexPath.row].date


var date:String

self.date = date
```

this is feedvc

```
    //MARK: FIREBASE GET DATAS
    func getDatas(){
        let firestoreDB = Firestore.firestore()
        
        firestoreDB.collection("Post").order(by: "date", descending: true).addSnapshotListener { snapshot, error in
            if error != nil {
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Error while getting data from server!" )
            }else{
                if snapshot?.isEmpty != true && snapshot != nil {
                    self.postArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
                    for document in snapshot!.documents{
                        if let imageURL = document.get("imageUrl") as? String{
                            if let caption = document.get("caption") as? String{
                                if let email = document.get("email") as? String{
                                    if let date = document.get("date") as? String{
                                    let post = Post(email: email, caption: caption, imageUrl: imageURL, date: date)
                                    self.postArray.append(post)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! FeedCell
        self.getUserInfo(userEmail: postArray[indexPath.row].email,cell: cell)
        cell.captionLabel.text =  postArray[indexPath.row].caption
        cell.CurrentTime.text = postArray[indexPath.row].date
        cell.postImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: postArray[indexPath.row].imageUrl))
        return cell
    }

}
```

this is feedcell

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import SDWebImage

class FeedCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var CurrentTime: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var userNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var postImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var captionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var userProfileImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var cardView: UIView!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        containerView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        cardView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        postImage.layer.masksToBounds = true
        containerView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        containerView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.25
        containerView.layer.shadowOffset = .zero
        containerView.layer.shadowRadius = 10
        
        containerView.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: containerView.bounds).cgPath
        
        containerView.layer.shouldRasterize = true

        containerView.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
        
    }
    
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
```

this is the post

```
import Foundation

struct Post{
    var email:String
    var caption:String
    var imageUrl:String
    var date:String
    
    init(email:String,caption:String,imageUrl:String,date:String) {
        self.email = email
        self.caption = caption
        self.imageUrl = imageUrl
        self.date = date
    }
}
```

`code`

Comment: Looks fine. Show what snapshot prints out.

Comment: shows these->Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2022-06-21 16:57:22.545971-0700 WisdWins[33879:1201943] [boringssl] boringssl_metrics_log_metric_block_invoke(153) Failed to log metrics

Comment: But after I delete the DATE, there are still these snapshots, which doesn't seem to be the problem